# Cocoa round cancel button

Tags: cocoa, button, interface-builder

Apple uses a small rounded button to cancel downloads and delete inputs in textfields but I can't find it anywhere. I also need the pause and play versions of this button. Here's the cancel button so you se what I mean.

[image: This is the button in the downloads window]

[image: the cancel button in spotlight]

I've looked for it in the object library in IB and checked all the setting but I can't find it anywhere. It's also used a lot in iOS. Can anyone tell me where to find it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's:

```
[NSImage imageNamed:NSImageNameStopProgressFreestandingTemplate];
```

([from the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSImageNameStopProgressFreestandingTemplate)).

Comment: Any idea about pause and play buttons?

Comment: The complete set of predefined image templates is listed in NSImage.h. (They’re not all in the documentation.) As it says, “If there is no image available for the situation you're interested in, please file a bug and use your own custom art in the meantime.”